# javascript time() using more Zero values?

Tags: javascript

iam working on this javascript Jquery plugin

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

for example its using time line to convert it to real time

like

```
var data = [
    {
        label: "United States",
        data: [[1220565600000, 0], [1320565600000, '13']]
    }
];
```

does this time lines same as php `time()` value ?

because when i replace them with php `time()` value its show 2 years later

Comment: JS returns timestamps in milliseconds, PHP's `time()` function does it in seconds; your approach in PHP would be `microtime(true)`.

Comment: you can use `time() * 1000`

Comment: my time stamp stored as time() in each row in database so if i called back i have to use $time[timestamp]*1000 right ?